# Translation of 'right'

Tags: traduction

Is there a French equivalent of 'right' being used to confirm a fact that the speaker thinks is true, as in 'You are from France right?' or 'He is your best friend right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a question, you might use various expressions including :

> Vous êtes français, c'est bien ça ?

> Vous êtes français, c'est ça ?

> Vous êtes français, on est bien d'accord ? (not whatever the context)

> Vous êtes français, c'est exact ?

> Vous êtes français, oui ?

> Vous êtes français, n'est-ce pas ? (formal)

> Vous êtes bien français ?

I think the latter would be my preferred choice.

What you would **not** use is *en effet*, *effectivement* because they are only use to acknowledge something already known to be true, i.e. in a reply:

> Oui, en effet.

> Oui, effectivement.

Other phrases used in the question might also be used in its reply:

> Oui, c'est bien ça.

> Oui, c'est ça.

> Oui, c'est exact.

> Oui, je suis bien français.

Comment: Can you give an example of a situation where en effet/ effectivement is used?

Comment: They can be used in the reply. Answer updated.